# Magento 2 Checkout Page billing address dropdown remove show direct billing address form

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, billing-address

Magento 2 I want to Checkout Page  billing address dropdown remove show direct billing address form.

This dropdown i want to remove
[image]

And show direct billing address form.This type
[image]

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code to remove address-list dropdown and show billing-address form direct.

Create `requirejs-config.js` file on below path to add mixin for billing-address.js in your custom module.

`app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
config: {
    mixins: {
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address': {
            'Vendor_Module/js/view/billing-address-mixin': true
        }
    }
}
```

};

Add mixin file `billing-address-mixin.js` on below path

`app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/billing-address-mixin.js`

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list',
  'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
  'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-billing-address',
  'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
  'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
],
function (
  $,
  addressList,
  quote,
  selectBillingAddress,
  checkoutData,
  customerData
) {
  'use strict';
  var lastSelectedBillingAddress = null,
    countryData = customerData.get('directory-data'),
    addressOptions = addressList().filter(function (address) {
      return address.getType() === 'customer-address';
    });

  return function (Component) {
    return Component.extend({

      /**
       * @return {Boolean}
       */
      useShippingAddress: function () {
        if (this.isAddressSameAsShipping()) {
          selectBillingAddress(quote.shippingAddress());

          this.updateAddresses();
          this.isAddressDetailsVisible(true);
        } else {
          lastSelectedBillingAddress = quote.billingAddress();
          quote.billingAddress(null);
          this.isAddressDetailsVisible(false);
          $('.field.field-select-billing').hide();
          this.isAddressFormVisible(true);
        }
        checkoutData.setSelectedBillingAddress(null);

        return true;
      }
    });
  };
});
```

I hope this will help you. Thanks!

Comment: i have try your code not working. Please help me

Comment: @MohitPatel there might some conflicts with your custom theme or module, did you checked this on fresh magento?

Comment: Also, i have try fresh Magento  but not success.

Comment: Strange! Can you please let me know on checkout page `billing-address-mixin.js` is loading or not?

Comment: Above code possible add billing-address.js file and how? Please help me

Comment: @MohitPatel this is working on my end please check video on this link https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/3270476?key=e3e0f0f3e29a24a0f4fdba3f2c131972

Comment: Let me know if there is any update.

Comment: Yes,Your working but i want to add code in billing-address.js file.This file is mageplaza OSC module

Comment: You can override it in your custom theme

Comment: Great Working your code. THANKS.

Comment: Please help me this question :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/336336/85907

Comment: Hey bro, actually I am running out of time due to my regular work. I will try to look into it and help you out.

Comment: Yes, Please check and help me.i am stuck in this

Comment: Hello @rahul barot pls help in above question.