# Remove "My billing and shipping address are the same" checkbox and Billing address form open By default Magento 2

Tags: magento2, billing-address, onestepcheckout

I am using the one step checkout and it is working fine.

Now, requirement is that , remove the "My billing and shipping address are the same" checkbox and open the Billing address form by default on load.

Please check this screenshot,
[image]

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use jquery to remove checkbox and show form by default on page load or you can change this behavior by overriding the corresponding js in your theme. Check similar solution for default magento checkout https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/335070/84221

Comment: Okay, let me try that code... will update you.

Comment: @RahulBarot, I am using swisupp Firecheckout module and there is already declared code in requirejs-config.js and i have replace the billing-address-mixin.js code with your code. But it is not working. Please check screenshots, https://nimb.ws/7UhrCz and https://nimb.ws/RiGrJt . That is the original code right now.

Comment: you may need to check with your swisupp Firecheckout module as there might be something which is causing conflicts. Also you can add logger in my code in order to check whether it is executing or not.